# Excel: Averaging Sensor Data by Time Stamp

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a device that collects temperature measurements from several sensors at discreet time intervals. This data is dumped into a .csv file with each row formatted as: [time] [sensor name] [temperature]. Each time stamp has three to five temperature measurements associated with it.

For each time stamp, I'm looking for a way to get min, max, and average of temperature across all sensors. My data set is large (between 50k and 150k rows), so the method would need to consist of formulas and/or VBA.

After extensive searching, the closest thing I've found is the averageif function, which I can't get to work with the large data set I'm working with. I would appreciate any suggestions on a place to start.

Comment: Do you think we're a script writing service? Please show what you have tried yourself so we can see where things are going wrong.

Comment: No, I don't expect someone to write a script for me. After about an hour of searching, the closest thing I've found is the averageif function, which I can't get to work with the large data set I'm working with. I'm looking for suggestions on a place to start.

Comment: Then please [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/797412/edit) to include this (what you tried), information like that is very helpful for us so we can understand what you want.

Comment: Please share the formula you are trying to use, what errors it gives and how your data is arranged? Otherwise, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot tables are exactly for that (and it keeps you away from VBA). Follow these steps:

- Create a Pivot table and select your data as input
- Put Timestamps in the row labels
- Put Sensor name in the column labels
- Put Temperature in the Value field and change it to express minimum value
- Put Temperature in the Value field and change it to express average value
- Put Temperature in the Value field and change it to express maximum value

Wow! That looks great! ;-)

[image: Pivot table of temperature data from two sensors]